# Эффективное хранение списка файлов

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть N-ое кол-во директорий, в каждой директории хранится M файлов с уникальными именами, которые не пересекаются с файлами из других директорий.

Как бы эффективно это все поместить в словарь, что бы по названию файла я мог получить директорию, где он лежит, а ключ+значения= путю к файлу?

Решение в лоб- это на каждый ключ дублировать путь, но тогда получится, что путь к одной и той же директории будет дублироваться несколько раз, что скушает ОЗУ.

Comment: 1) Получить список всех директорий. 2) Для каждой директории получить список файлов и загнать в словарь, указать директорию как значение, имя файла как ключ.

Comment: Да, но получится, что 10 файлов из одной директории будут ссылаться на 10 строк, а это расточительство по памяти.

Comment: 10 файлов будут ссылать на одну и ту же строку, если они в одной и той же директории

Comment: Да, но по памяти будет 10 строк на 10 файлов, а не 1 единая строка.

Comment: Памяти будет 1 строка и 10 ссылок на неё

Comment: Но строка же не ссылочный тип => каждая новая строка- это новое значение в памяти или я что-то упустил из вашего ответа?

Comment: Добавил  пример ответом

Comment: String только ведет себя как значимый тип, но сам по себе он ссылочный.

Comment: String не ведет себя как значимый тип, это чисто ссылочный неизменяемый тип

Comment: @rdorn, мне всегда казалось, что передаче строки в методы создается ее копия => я предполагал, что в словарь будет добавлять копия одной и той же строки, но ссылающиеся на разные объекты.

Comment: @iluxa1810 это неверно. Одно из преимуществ того, что строка неизменяемая - то, что можно одну и ту же строку хоть куда передать и все будет работать.

Comment: @tym32167 не нравится слово "ведет как значимый" - пусть будет "подражает значимым", суть от этого не меняется, зато легче доносится. Неизменяемый - правильное определение, только оно ни разу не объясняет суть того, что происходит.

Comment: @rdorn я в принципе не понял, что вы имели ввиду под `ведет себя как значимый`. Теперь ясно, что это вопрос терминологии и вы имели ввиду то же, что я. Потому ваш способ описания неизменяемости, по крайней мере для меня, был неинформативен и больше меня запутал, чем что то объяснил, потому я вам и возразил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как пример:

```
var root = @"C:\.....root_dir";

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);

foreach (var d in directories)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(d).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x));
    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        dictionary.Add(f, d);
    }
}
```

Как видите, директория добавляется для соседних файлов одна и та же. То есть для 10 соседних файлов будет ссылка на одну и ту же директорию

Comment: Да, я сейчас проверил через Object.ReferenceEquals и строка по одному ключу ровна строке по другому => я ошибался.

Comment: @iluxa1810 есть вариант проще `Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).IsValueType);`